# CSS Problem in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, css

I've got a problem in my M2.3.2 site which is affecting the customer login controls on the My Account page.

[image]

It's breaking the layout and I think it's being caused by core Magento css contained in vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/css/docs/docs.css

The css is rendering a class from print css and the only place I've found it is

`@media all and (min-width: 768px), print {
  .example-responsive-block {
    background: #ccf;
  }
  .example-responsive-block:before {
    content: 'Desktop styles ';
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}`

on the front end of the website and I'm not sure that

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px), print {
```

is how to write css ANDs

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your css file

```
#maincontent .login-container .fieldset > .field > .control {
    width: 50%;
}
.contact-index-index #maincontent .column:not(.sidebar-additional) .form.contact {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Clear cache,static files, do a static content deploy

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: That fixed it thank you very much. 

Any idea why the core has that css in it? It doesn't appear to be correctly formatted to me.